# Unable to Delete empty folders of directory and sub-directory using batch

Tags: batch-file

with the help of batch file I am able to delete files from the main directory and sub directories but I am finding it difficult to delete empty sub directories left after files inside it got deleted . I have written script but it is not working for deleting empty sub directories part

**MY Batch Script**

```
@echo off
Set _Extentions=".LOG"
Set _FolderList= "D:\FCS"
Set _FolderList=%_FolderList% "D:\SMSGateway\SMSLogs"
Set _NoOfDays=15
for %%s in (%_FolderList%) do (
                  for %%d in (%_Extentions%) do (
                              call :process_Deletion %%s %%d
                                )
)

:process_Deletion
IF [%1] == [] GOTO EndOfFun
set _ParaPath=%1
set _ParaExtn=%2

echo forfiles /P %_ParaPath% /S /m *%_ParaExtn% /D -%_NoOfDays% /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @path @fdate @ftime"

echo forfiles /P %_ParaPath% /S /m *%_ParaExtn% /D -%_NoOfDays% /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @file" 

echo for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir %_FolderList% /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"

:EndOfFun

EXIT /B
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Please help..

Answer (score -1):

Empty directories require `rd` or `rmdir`

https://www.computerhope.com/rmdirhlp.htm

> The rd and rmdir commands remove empty directories in MS-DOS. To delete directories with files or directories within them, you must use the deltree command. If you are running Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows XP, use the /S option.

Comment: I tried with "do rmdir" , it gives same result . !!! is my --- echo for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir %_FolderList% /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rmdir "%%d"--- format correct?

Comment: @AlokSharma - you rather need `rd /s /q  "c:\some\path"`

Comment: @npocmaka - rd /s /q  %_FolderList%!! added this in place of "%%d" at the end but still same issue . can u help me with this command which u have given wrt to my script ? .